# Oracle Create Table without Insert permission

Tags: oracle, permissions, oracle10g

Is it possible in oracle dbms for a user to have the permission to create a table but not have the permission to insert in it although the same user just created it?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer:

No, it's not.

#### Longer answer:

You can do pretty much anything you want. If you want to restrict insert access the usual method would be to create the table in a different schema. Assuming you have a table `emp` in the schema `hr`, which you wanted to access from the schema 'users`:

You would [grant](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF01603) `users` permission to SELECT from the table `emp` when connected as `hr`:

```
grant select on emp to users
```

or, if you also want `users` to be able to UPDATE `emp`:

```
grant select, update on emp to users
```

Lastly, when connected as `users`, you prefix the table name with the schema it is located in:

```
select * from hr.emps
```

You can now select from the table but not insert into it.